# LINQ returns wrong number of items when DataLoadOptions is set

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Here is a code example:

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();

Symbol symbol = (from s in context.Symbols where s.ID = 3257 select s).First();
ProtocolVariable[] variables = symbol.ProtocolVariables.ToArray();    

context.Dispose();
```

Using debugger I see that number of variables equals to 3 (variables.Length == 3).
Now I change code a little bit:

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();

DataLoadOptions dlo = new dataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Symbol>(s => s.ProtocolVariables);
context.LoadOptions = dlo;

Symbol symbol = (from s in context.Symbols where s.ID = 3257 select s).First();
ProtocolVariable[] variables = symbol.ProtocolVariables.ToArray();    

Context.Dispose();
```

Debugger now is showing me that number of variables equals to 1.

How is that possible?

Here is some addition information (I don't know if it is important):

- "Symbols" is a Table
- "ProtocolVariables" is a View
- Association between "Symbols" and "ProtocolVariables" I added using *.dbml file.

Here is a SQL query behind first code example:

```
SELECT 
[t0].[ID], 
[t0].[SubsystemID], 
[t0].[GenericName], 
[t0].[LocalName], 
[t0].[TypeID], 
[t0].[Array], 
[t0].[Array2], 
[t0].[UnitID], 
[t0].[Description], 
[t0].[ProtocolID]
FROM [dbo].[Symbols] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ID] = 3257
```

Here is SQL query behind second code example:

```
SELECT 
[t0].[ID], 
[t0].[SubsystemID], 
[t0].[GenericName], 
[t0].[LocalName], 
[t0].[TypeID], 
[t0].[Array], 
[t0].[Array2], 
[t0].[UnitID], 
[t0].[Description], 
[t0].[ProtocolID], 
[t1].[ID] AS [ID2], 
[t1].[SymbolID], 
[t1].[SubsystemID] AS [SubsystemID2], 
[t1].[GenericName] AS [GenericName2], 
[t1].[LocalName] AS [LocalName2], 
[t1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID2], 
[t1].[Array] AS [Array3], 
[t1].[Array2] AS [Array22], 
[t1].[UnitID] AS [UnitID2], 
[t1].[Description] AS [Description2], 
[t1].[ProtocolID] AS [ProtocolID2], 
[t1].[VariableTypeID], 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[ProtocolVariables] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[SymbolID] = [t0].[ID]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Symbols] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ProtocolVariables] AS [t1] ON [t1].[SymbolID] = [t0].[ID]
WHERE [t0].[ID] = 3257
ORDER BY [t0].[ID], [t1].[ID]
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Post the exact SQL that was executed in both variants. Capture using SQL Profiler.

Comment: Is it Linq to Sql or Entity Framework?

Comment: Thank you for the tip: please take a look at the SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue: ID fields in "ProtocolVariables" view must be unique.

I cannot skilfully explain it. I can only describe it - I hope it will save you some time.

1. I added table "Symbols" to *.dbml file.
2. I added view "ProtocolVariables" to *.dbml file.
3. I wanted to add Association between Symbols.ID -> ProtocolVariables.SymbolID

   - I made ProtocolVariable.ID Primary Key (otherwise VS showed me warning)
   - I added Association
   - I used NEWID function to generate unique values for ProtocolVariable.ID

Without last step (NEWID function) I observed behaviour which I described in my question.